# All visual studio 2010 projects go "out of date" whenever i re-start my system

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have 200 hundred odd project in my Visual Studio 2010 solution. I do build "Build Solution" when I start my day. The problem is, if I re-boot my system, I cannot run the projects directly, as I get "projects out of date". I am very sure that I did not modify even a single source file or header file. As I investigate further, I find all the projects are out of date. So I have to build my complete solution again, which takes more than 2 hours. So, is there any way to prevent this issue.

I checked with my system time, my system time is upto date. Also the system time will be advanced than the xxx.exe date modified, but still I get "projects out of date" window.
I am pretty concerned with this issue as a lot of time goes for building. Is there any way for me to get out of this condition.?

Thanks All,
Kushal